# How to get edited values in ObservableCollectionin WPF(MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
 public class PricingGrpModel
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }     
 }

 private ObservableCollection<PricingGrpModel> _myCollection;    
 public ObservableCollection<PricingGrpModel> myCollection
 {
  get { return _myCollection; }
  set { _myCollection= value; OnPropertyChanged("myCollection"); }
 }

myCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(myCollection_CollectionChanged);   

void myCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {                 
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:                       
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {              
    }
}
```

I have bound 'myCollection' ObservableCollection to DataGrid's ItemsSource. The Collection Change event fired while adding or removing the Row. But I couldn't track the changes of existing row value. how can I get a notification when an item's property in an ObservableCollection has been changed?

Comment: You want `PricingGrpModel` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: just to clarify: ObservableCollection is not aware of particular changes on the items, ObservableCollection can inform you just about the changes on itself, e.g. new items or removed items. Therefor as Chris Wohlert commented you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on PricingGrpModel to be able to handle any changes on each individual objects.

Comment: "PricingGrpModel" class is an entity class, it's meant generated from EF, So how could I implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged'..?

Comment: Create `PricingGrpViewModel`

Comment: can't we do without creating a new class?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NewItems` and `OldItems` properties of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`.

When you call ObservableCollection.Remove(), the removed items will be present in OldItems property:

```
void myCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
         foreach (var removedItem in e.OldItems)
         {
         }
    }
}
```

The only problem is, that when you call `ObservableCollection.Clear()` method, the OldItems property is null.

If you want to access also cleared items, you will have to create your custom class by inheriting from ObservableCollection and override RemoveItem protected method. **RemoveItem method is invoked also when you call ObservableCollection.Clear()** You can use my ExtendedObservableCollection from this answer: [Trigger InotifyPropertyChanged/CollectionChanged on ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444874/trigger-inotifypropertychanged-collectionchanged-on-observablecollection/30486363#30486363)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly track the item Changes via the CollectionChanged Event.
What you can do is:
Add and Remove an EventHandler to the `PricingGrpModel.PropertyChanged` in the `CollectionChanged` EventHandler for each item in the ObservableCollection.